# multiple ajax requests without page refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, struts2

i have an app (struts2+sprin+glassfish3.1.2) that sends an ajax (jquery) requests every second to the server. If certain conditions are met my js redirects me to other page, otherwise i do nothing.
It seems that after a long period (couple of hours without any redirect) the browser become unresponsive or it take a very long to time perform a request.
I mention that if when this happens i close the browser from the X and reopen it everything is ok. I did not manage to replicate this problem in my test environment, but it seems the i have this problem in production :( .

### any ideea ?

i use Jquery (struts2-jquery-plugin3.3.0)   for ajax calls,i will attach some of the code:
this method is accessed every 1 second :

```
function checkedForAnsweredCalls(){

    if (ajaxFinished == 1){

        ajaxFinished = 0;

        $.getJSON('redirectToTicket.html',
                function(data) {

                    ajaxFinished = 1;
                    if (data != null){                      
                        window.location = data;         
                    }
                }
        );
    }


    };
```

by this piece of code:

```
<script>
            var ajaxFinished = 1;
            window.setInterval( "checkedForAnsweredCalls()", 1000 );            
        </script>
```

this ajax code access a struts2 action that has a json response type, so if some database conditions are met i get back an url.
thanks for the quick responses.

Comment: I would recommend that you post the code that does the AJAX request. Also some details about what it is making the request to could help people answer your questions (i.e. what server side language are you using, possibly a bit of that code, etc...)

Comment: i have updated with the code that performs ajax call, any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Use Firebug to profile your web application, should tell you where the hangs are occurring.

As for doing multiple Ajax requests without page refreshes, you would probably need some sort of ajax-managing library, either hand-written or freely available (prototype.js is one example).

I use the following code to manage it for me, can't take credit for it, its a mishmash of code I found Googling around and I've made some minor changes.

```
var reqObj_arr = [];

function getXMLObject(index) {
    if(reqObj_arr[index]){
        return reqObj_arr[index];
    }

    var xmlHttp = false;
    try {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")  // For Old Microsoft Browsers
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")  // For Microsoft IE 6.0+
        } catch (e2) {
            xmlHttp = false   // No Browser accepts the XMLHTTP Object then false
        }
    }
    if (!xmlHttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();        //For Mozilla, Opera Browsers
    }
    reqObj_arr[index] = xmlHttp;
    return xmlHttp;  // Mandatory Statement returning the ajax object created
}

    function ajaxFunction(url, target, params) {
        var getdate = new Date();  //Used to prevent caching during ajax call
        var xmlhttp = new getXMLObject(target);    //xmlhttp holds the ajax object

        if(xmlhttp) {
            xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true); //calling url using POST method
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange  = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                    if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Error during AJAX call. Please try again");
                    }
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            if(params){
                xmlhttp.send(params); // Posting to PHP file
            }
            else{
                xmlhttp.send(); // Posting to PHP file
            }
        }
    }
```

To use it, add the following line of Javascript into your page

```
var url = 'URL to the .php file';
var target = 'ID of the element to add retrieved data to';
var params = 'Any other parameters to send';
ajaxFunction(url,target,params);
```